# Combining random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

On combining random variables and their means, [this article](http://stattrek.com/random-variable/combination.aspx) states:

> Suppose you have two variables: $X$ with a mean of $μ_{x}$ and $Y$
> with a mean of $μ_{y}$. The mean of the sum of these variables
> $μ_{x+y}$ and the mean of the difference between these variables
> $μ_{x-y}$ are given by the following equations:
>
> $μ_{x+y} = μ_{x} + μ_{y}$
>
> $μ_{x-y} = μ_{x} - μ_{y}$

The article assumes that the reader knows what $x+y$ means. I understand $x+5$, where $5$ is added to all the possible outcomes of $x$, but what exactly is $x+y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means follow the rule of linearity .

$E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y] $

It doesn't matter whether the events are independent or not . So for any linear combination of random variables you can take the mean of the individual random variables and then combine them .

You are asking for the intuition for $X+Y$ . These are two events whose outcome can be defined by these two random variables . Suppose you have a game where you throw a coin $10$ times , and the reward for $x$ heads is $x \ \$$  and you will get to throw a six-sided die $x$ number of times and suppose you get a reward of $12$*(the number of $1$'s you get in $x$ number of times you throw the dice) . Let the reward for throwing a dice be $Y$ . Then the total reward you can get from this game is defined by the random variable $X+Y$.

Comment: and the notation in this article $E[X]$ is equaivalent to $\mu_x$